# Kubernetes local testing setup

Tags: google-chrome, kubernetes

I've found that it is hard to use minikube to run local tests that depend on certain containers to be running. For instance using a remote headless-chrome to run some tests:

```
  containers:
  - image: chrome-test
    imagePullPolicy: Never
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80

  - image: headless-chrome
    imagePullPolicy: Never
    ports: 
    - containerPort: 8910
    securityContext:
      capabilities:
        add:
        - SYS_ADMIN
```

I've found it easier to use docker-compose for instances like these. That way I don't have to deal with deleting pods, and finding log outputs. I understand this is a pretty open ended question, but I figure any information in this area could be helpful. 
What is the best way to test multiple containers with kubernetes?

Comment: Why is using docker-compose any easier?

Comment: The main reasons I've found are that: (1) Logs are defaulted to std out  (2) It only takes one command to run and delete the containers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use docker-compose, but using minikube is also very easy to test things.

So for my testing I do following steps:

- Create new Kubernetes `Namespace`
- Deploy artifacts(here you deploy the `deployment`)
- Expose that `deployment` with a `service` of type `NodePort`
- Now all you need is to find out what random port was chosen as nodePort and curl on that port with `minikube ip:nodePort`
- If you want logs of the pod you can get that as well
- Once you see all the things you wanna see, just delete the `Namespace`.

I have done similar things while doing end to end testing of the tool called [kedge](https://github.com/kedgeproject/kedge) which generates Kubernetes artifacts, so we deploy all generated artifacts on a running cluster in similar way I have mentioned above, ref: [here](https://github.com/kedgeproject/kedge/pull/77).